# Is it possible to trigger on Sandbox creation?

Tags: apex, trigger

Is there an operation when creating/deploying a Sandbox org that would allow you to develop an Apex trigger to send an email out to administrators? If not through a trigger, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a sandbox is ready, the creator will be notified by email. There's no way to run a trigger or other code that would send an alert when a Sandbox has been created or refreshed.

Answer (score 2):

While there is no "on org create" trigger, I think there actually would be a way to notify a mailing list when a new org is provisioned. This is untested but should work. It's a bit of work but if you really want this, you should be able to do it. Steps would be something like:

- create a List custom setting, with a name of something like "Current Org ID" and a text field.
- create a scheduled job that runs, say once per hour. That job queries the current Org's ID (`UserInfo.getOrganizationId()`) and then queries the custom setting. If the custom setting does not exist, or does not match the current Org ID, send an email to the administrator list notifying them of the new Org.
- That job then saves the Org ID into the custom setting so the logic won't fire again.

Semi-unrelated, but if you happen to also need a method to find whether you're in a sandbox, and what edition you're on, [this](http://www.michaelforce.org/recipeView?id=a0Ga000000Ekp65EAB) fits the bill.

Comment: This might work, but aren't sandboxes provisioned with email set to only send password resets and other system emails now? You have to go in to the sandbox and tell it it is ok to send all mail.

Comment: Good point @DanielHoechst, seems like it would be better to just have the scheduled class run whatever code they intended to execute on the org creation.  Would be really awesome way to setup the default config for a sandbox automatically

Comment: Daniel - yes good point, hadn't thought of that. I guess maybe a web service call could work around that restriction, but now this is getting to be a pretty over-engineered solution to something that doesn't sound much like a problem :)

Comment: Would a way around the restricted email be to just kick off a reset email for my refreshed sandbox account? Is that possible? Then I'd be notified that a sandbox is created/refreshed since I have a password reset for it.